# lme4: Handling lmer "convergence code: 0"

Tags: r, optimization, lme4, convergence

I am currently calculating a multi-level analysis with 32 countries (country variable "CNTRY3"). The dependent variable is the willingness to pay for environmental protection "WTP" (scale 1 - 5, centred). I have included four random slopes in the third step (Random Intercept Random Slope) of the multi-level analysis (I would like to vary these based on my theory):

- RINC_ALL_z -> Income per person (z-standardized)
- social_trust (scale 1 - 5, centered) -> trust in other people
- political_trust (scale 1 - 5, centred) -> trust in politics
- EC_cen (scale 1 - 5, centered) -> Environmental awareness

.

```
modell.3a <- lmer(WTP ~ RINC_ALL_z + social_trust_cen + political_trust_cen + 
                   Men + lowest_degree + middle_degree + requirement_university +
                   uncompleted_university + university_degree + AGE_cen + urban + 
                   EC_cen + (RINC_ALL_z + social_trust_cen + political_trust_cen + 
                               EC_cen|CNTRY3), data=ISSP2010_1)
```

Then the error message appears:

> convergence code: 0 Model failed to converge with max|grad| =
>   0.00527884 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

Now I was able to research that if you calculate the model with the optimizer "BOBYQA", for example, these "convergence warnings" can be bypassed. And indeed, if I calculate the model like this, then no convergence warning appears any more:

```
modell.3b <- lmer(WTP ~ RINC_ALL_z + social_trust_cen + political_trust_cen + 
               Men + lowest_degree + middle_degree + requirement_university +
               uncompleted_university + university_degree + AGE_cen + urban + 
               EC_cen + (RINC_ALL_z + social_trust_cen + political_trust_cen + 
                           EC_cen|CNTRY3), data=ISSP2010_1, control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
                                                                                  optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e5)))
```

So I read in this very interesting [article](http://svmiller.com/blog/2018/06/mixed-effects-models-optimizer-checks/) that if you use one optimizer, you should compare it with all other available optimizers to find out if certain optimizers influence the parameters of the regression. No sooner said than done (with the variable environmental awareness), I replicated the graphs of the article, but unfortunately the optimizers are not in one column (loglikelihood / t-value) as in the article. I have attached the two pictures here. My interpretation would be, regarding the log-likelihood comparison and the t-value comparison, that the majority (5) of the optimizers are in one column (including my used "BOBYQA" ) and only 2 optimizers differ from the majority of optimizers, so my used optimizer should not influence the parameters, right?

[Loglikelihood comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHaw0.png)

[T-Value Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqPSL.png)

The first question would be what such an optimizer does (you just read that you should use optimizers to avoid convergence issues)?
The second question I have is, would you agree with this interpretation of the two diagrams?

I would be very happy about an answer, I have been thinking about this for several days... :-(

Many greetings
Joern